# Looking for the Total, count, and average of the numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a program that repeatedly reads numbers until the users enter `"done"`. Once `"done"` is entered, print out the `total`, `count`, and an `average` of the numbers.

If the user enters anything other than a number, detect their mistake using try and except and print an error message and skip to the next number.

**Here is the code:**

```
num = 0
tot = 0.0
while True:
    sval = input("enter a number: ")
    if sval == 'done':
        break
    try:
        fval = float(sval)
    except:
        print("Invalid Dumbass")
        continue
num = num + 1
tot = tot + fval

print("all done")
print(tot,num,tot/num)
```

**Output**

```
enter a number: 4
enter a number: 5
enter a number: 6
enter a number: done
all done
6.0 1 6.0
```

Comment: please format your code. refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: You just need to put `num` and `tot` calculation inside the loop. Also print the total, avg etc. only if `num` is greater than 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations were outside of the loop.

```py
num = 0
tot = 0.0
while True:
    sval = input("enter a number: ")
    if sval == 'done':
        break
    try:
        fval = float(sval)
        num = num + 1
        tot = tot + fval

    except:
        print("Invalid Dumbass")
        continue

print("all done")
print(tot,num,tot/num)
```